# question about supremum of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $f(x)=x+\sin x, \: x \in \mathbb{R}$, then there is an infinite real sequence as follows:
$$
y_0=1, \;y_1=6, \; \text{and} \: y_{n+1}=
\begin{cases}
f(y_n)& y_n \geq y_{n-1}\\
f(y_n+\frac{\pi}{2})-\frac{\pi}{2} & y_n < y_{n-1}
\end{cases} \;\text{where}  \; n \in \mathbb{Z}^\ast.
$$

---

I want to obtain the supremum (or the least upper bound) $M$ of this sequence. However, I have no idea how to evaluate it and any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will admit I wasn't sure where to start until I ran a simulation of this sequence. I then came up with some conjectures based off of the simulations and proved them. Also, I'm not sure what you meant by $\mathbb{Z}^*$. I'll assume you meant $\mathbb{N}$.

First, let's simplify this. Notice that $sin(x + \pi/2) = cos(x)$. Basically,

$$y_{n+1} = \begin{cases}
y_n + sin(y_n) &\text{ if } y_n \geq y_{n-1}\\
y_n + cos(y_n) &\text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

I will assume you can directly compute the first few terms. The point is, $y_3 < 6$ and $y_4 > 2\pi > y_3$. Then $y_5 = y_4 + \sin(y_4) > y_4$, and this continuous as long as $y_n < 3 \pi$, because $\sin(y_n) > 0$ for $2\pi < y_n < 3\pi$.

Take note of the fact that $\sin(x) < x$ for $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$ (you can prove this by noting that $\sin(0) = 0$ and $\frac{d}{dx}\sin(x) = \cos(x) \leq 1 = \frac{d}{dx}x$).

Then, for $x < 3\pi-1$, $x + \sin(x) < 3\pi$. This is trivially true. Now suppose that $3\pi-1\leq x < 3\pi$. Then,

$$x + \sin(x) = x + \sin(3\pi-x) < x + 3\pi - x = 3\pi.$$

So we've established that $y_n$ is an increasing sequence for $n\geq 4$. We've also established that $y_n < 3\pi$ for all $n$ and that $\sup_n y_n > \frac{5\pi}{2}$.

Finally, to prove convergence, note that $\sin(x) \geq x - \frac{x^3}{6}$. Then for $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$, $\frac{\sin(x)}{x} > 1 - \frac{x^2}{6}$. If $y_n > \frac{5\pi}{2}$ (which is true of $n\geq 6$),

\begin{align*}
3\pi - y_{n+1} &= 3\pi - y_n - \sin(y_n) = 3\pi - y_n - \sin(3\pi - y_n)\\
& < 3\pi - y_n - 3\pi + y_n + \frac{(3\pi-y_n)^3}{6} < \frac{1}{2}(3\pi - y_n)
\end{align*}

The last inequality results because $\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2 < 3$. Thus,

$$3\pi - y_{n+k} < \frac{1}{2^k}(3\pi - y_n) \rightarrow 0$$

So $y_n \nearrow 3\pi$, which makes $3\pi$ the supremum of $\{y_n\}$.